# Unable to login to keycloak using master realm credentials

Tags: authentication, keycloak

I am using keycloak operator to install keycloak and i have configured keycloak to use external database (RDS instance). ==> (externalDatabase: true)

The keycloak instances are up and running without any issues.

When i tried to login to the keycloak UI with master realm credentials it is telling that the credentials are invalid, though the credentials are correct.

I am getting the credentials using the following command.

`kubectl get secret credential-test -o go-template='{{range $k,$v := .data}}{{printf "%s: " $k}}{{if not $v}}{{$v}}{{else}}{{$v | base64decode}}{{end}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}'`

The following is the log from the instance.

`07:40:48,172 WARN [org.keycloak.events] (default task-1) type=LOGIN_ERROR, realmId=master, clientId=security-admin-console, userId=566f4e3e-c0f1-4304-bca2-686321d88b87, ipAddress=10.242.3.61, error=invalid_user_credentials, auth_method=openid-connect, auth_type=code, redirect_uri=https://test123.net/auth/admin/master/console/, code_id=5561bc9e-e2b9-41e3-836d-37add6e74c1c, username=admin, authSessionParentId=5561bc9e-e2b9-41e3-836d-37add6e74c1c, authSessionTabId=Oq-orhggRE4`

Any advice or suggestion is highly appreciated.

Comment: For the admin, are you also generating the name?

Comment: Try with kubectl get secret credential-test -o go-template='{{range $k,$v := .data}}{{printf "%s: " $k}}{{if not $v}}{{$v  | base64decode}}{{else}}{{$v | base64decode}}{{end}}{{"\n"}}{{end}}' and tell me what do you got

Answer (score 1):

I had this, or a similar issue as well when setting up the operator.

It appears that the external database that supposedly stores the admin username and password isn't updated when a new secret is generated if, say, the CRD for the Keycloak instance is deleted along with the secret. The steps I went through to fix it was to:

1. Delete the CRD.
2. Delete the database.
3. Recreate the database.
4. Recreate the CRD.

That way, the database should have no reason to accept the new credentials.

There is probably a better solution. But I could not find it in the docs so far.